# Different color background in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, background, png

http://goo.gl/PMvYn
The slideshow images seem to be taking on a grey background only in IE 8 and below by inheriting a color from an LI item. Any idea why this would be?

Here's a picture of a side by side comparison of Chrome and IE.
http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/200/screenshot20120823at554.png